# Difference between "be suspicious of" and "suspect"?

Tags: differences

**Similar** questions have beens asked before, but I believe mine hasn't quite been answered.

In the game HITMAN™, holding a suspicious item and standing close to an NPC causes the word *Suspicious* to appear on screen, indicating that someone is suspicious of 47.

If I then described to someone why I failed Silent Assassin, would I say that someone

1. *suspected* me or
2. was *suspicious of* me

or do both expressions mean the same in this context?

Comment: Have you researched this and if so what have you found?

Comment: I have, if briefly. The results were rather... inconclusive. Some said both is fine, some claimed only one is correct, but I also tend towards "both is fine". I just wanna know because it nagged me since Day One.

Comment: You can say *I suspect that person*, but you can't normally say *I suspect that document* - probably because unless you explicitly specify ***what*** your suspicion is about the person or thing, the default assumption is *he/it **is guilty*** (was the cause of bad things happening, though not necessarily intentionally).

Comment: You can be suspicious of someone even if you've no idea what bad things they might do (or have done). But if you *suspect* them, you know what was done (and you think they might have done it).

Comment: ...I'm just pointing out a couple of contexts where the two usages are significantly different. Maybe someone on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) will tell you something more useful if the question gets migrated there (which is what I think should happen).

Comment: That's what I was searching for. So, if someone sees me holding a wrench or shooting with a silenced gun and *Suspicious* appears, they suspect me.

Answer (score 0):

Suspecting someone is somewhat stronger, more a belief, than being suspicious of someone which is more a feeling.

- The guard was suspicious of me.

Suspicious ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suspicious#Adjective)):

> Distrustful or tending to suspect.

If you gain enough distrust from the guard he will suspect you. When you acting so suspicious (e.g. running around too much or too often) the guard will suspect you to be intruder.

- The guard suspected me to be an intruder, because I was acting too suspicious.

To suspect ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suspect#Verb)):

> (transitive) To believe (someone) to be guilty.

I'd say you were suspected to be an intruder, because you were acting *too* suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

They both share a root morpheme passed down from Latin, to French, to English. They are related but an English speaker would be likely to detect nuance. One reason for this is that they are different parts of speech (Suspect(n.) Suspicious(adj.)) and different parts of speech have different functions in a language.